# Storing Rails partials in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views, erb

I need to allow users the ability to create lessons, which consist of HTML and form elements. I want them to be able to take advantage of Rails' form helpers and general Ruby code to, for example, decide where and how to display error content. I realize there are security issues with giving them access to execute Ruby code, but I'll have to deal with that later if users will share deployments.

So it seems I should store the ERB files in the database and somehow call them with `<%= render content_from_database %>`. Is this possible? Will I affect Rails caching in some way?

Using latest Rails with Heroku (no writing to filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Liquid template language](http://liquidmarkup.org/)

From their tagline:

> Ruby library for rendering safe templates which cannot affect the
>   security of the server they are rendered on.